# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms, session, post

I know there are a lot of questions here with the same title and problem but I've checked all of my syntax and I really have no clue why this doesn't work anymore (some time ago, it did work).

```
<?php
include_once("../../database/db_connect.php");
include '../../chromephp-master/ChromePhp.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

session_start();

ChromePhp::log('Start...');

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])) {

    ChromePhp::log('Nothing in the SESSION.');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        ChromePhp::log('Lets have a look at the data...');
        (...)
        ChromePhp::log('Login successful!');

        header('Location: news.php');
    } else {
        ChromePhp::log('Empty form.');
    }

} else {
    header('Location: news.php');
}
?>
```

My form looks as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="site/users/login" >
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Gebruikersnaam" /><br /><br />
    <input type="password" name="pwrd" value="Wachtwoord" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;Log in&nbsp;" />
</form>
```

The form is on the same page as the PHP code; I point the action to "site/users/login" because in the head of the HTML page, I set `<base href="../../">`.

When I submit the form, the page reloads and the log says "Start...", then "Nothing in the SESSION." and finally "Empty form.".

What am I doing wrong? All help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** This is the content of my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try without those `&nbsp;` in the value of the submit button.  You should not put html entities in the value attribute. Replace them by plain spaces if you need them.

Comment: From what you are saying 'log says "Start...", then "Nothing in the SESSION."' it appears that your code doesn't even reach the "isset($_POST['submit'])" statement, are you sure you have no session with login OR password data?, you could verify with var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: @ezzarghili It does, because it says "Empty form", which is the `else` part of that `if`-statement (outputs "Empty form"). It just fails, that's all (why I don't know).

Comment: @RayoVerweij Do a `var_dump($_POST);` before entering any of the `if`-statements, what does it contain?

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: @trincot @Qirel @BartFriederichs Hi all, thanks for the comments. Without the `&nbsp;`, it still doesn't work. `var_dump($_POST);` before any of the if-statements returns an empty array. Different browsers give the same results.

Comment: Please include your .htaccess file contents, there is a chance that the cause of this problem is in there.

Comment: @RayoVerweij sorry my mistake, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that comment.

Comment: @trincot I've edited the OP accordingly. Do you think it causes any problems?

Comment: No, it looks fine. Just to avoid the URL rewriting, could you add ".php" like this `action="site/users/login.php"`, and could you also remove the first include (just for test), to see if you get any different result? Could you provide the code (without revealing passwords) of db_connect.php?

Comment: @trincot I've built the page again from the ground up to specifically see where the issue occurs, and it appears to break when I send the data to another php file where the real login happens (in the (...) in my code). Strangely enough, instead of giving errors, it just reloads the page. If this reminds you of something you can say to help me, please do so; otherwise I'll look into that file (I haven't created it myself) and try to figure it out. Thanks anyway for the assistance!

Comment: That explains it. scan that file for `header("location: ....");` statements, which perform such redirecting. Such redirections will not forward the posted data, so it gets lost.

Comment: @trincot I've found the issue, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok, for completeness sake, I have turned my input into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible reasons why posted data does not arrive at your PHP page.

One could be that the **.htaccess** file has rules that are responsible for this effect. But after the contents were published in the question, it became clear that this was not the case.

Another could be that the script sends a redirection to (eventually) the same page, thereby losing the posted data. Once you mentioned in comments that you noticed that the browser reloaded the page right after submission, it became clear that this was the candidate cause to look for.

Redirection is typically done with this kind of code:

```
header("location: some-URL");
```

... and certainly when the argument contains a self-reference, like this:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

The code you posted did not contain such statement, at least not one that explains the behaviour, but there are some included scripts:

- `../../database/db_connect.php`
- `../../chromephp-master/ChromePhp.php`

and also some dots `...`, where we don't know what happens (includes could be there as well).

If any of these parts performs such a redirection, it could be at the cause of the problem. We can ignore **ChromePhp** which is a publicly available library and does not do such things.

So, at least **db_connect.php** but also all other included files (either directly or via other included files), should be scanned for code that redirects.

If you find such redirection, check if it is reasonable to keep that code -- as not all redirection is bad. But certainly self-redirections should be analysed: are they really necessary, knowing that any posted data will thereby be ignored?

So replace the causing `header()` statement(s) by more appropriate code and your problem should be solved.

As a side note: it is better not to put HTML entities inside a *value* attribute of an HTML element, like you have here:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;Log in&nbsp;" />
```

If you need the spacing, just enter plain spaces:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Log in " />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it worked for you because you were logged in (`$_SESSION['username']` and `$_SESSION['password']` were filled).

So, use data from `$_POST` to sign in user (`$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['pwrd']`).

Comment: But why is `$_POST["submit"]` not set? That is the question.

Comment: @trincot, oh, yeh. So it could happen by 3 reasons: 
1. Wrong route. Something got this request with POST and then redirected here;
2. Something stole POST data (it could be previous scripts or framework);
3. Restricted POST data with server's settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot '.php' after 'site/users/login'.

I have tried your code in simpler version and successed. The code like this:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
        echo $_POST['submit'];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <base href="../../">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="algorithm/debug_login.php" >
        <input type="text" name="username" value="Gebruikersnaam" /><br /><br />
        <input type="password" name="pwrd" value="Wachtwoord" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;Log in&nbsp;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is saying the script runs, so I guess that is not it.

Comment: It can point to a folder too, where the index-file is a .php file. Or it may be altered with htaccess.

Comment: It is indeed changed with an .htaccess file. Using `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` doesn't change anything either.